# creating new field on mysql

Tags: database, mysql, wp-user-query, customization

I would like to add extra sections like "gender" on the WordPress user database. I would like to draw information from this information later. For example, let's say I want to attract gender. I created custom registration pages using the "ultimate member" extensions for this, but nothing changed in the database. there is still information like "user name, nickname, e-mail, registration data" only.

Comment: You shouldn't modify the main WP tables to add extra data, that's what user meta is for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find any additional information in the usermeta table as meta_key meta_value pairs.
Wordpress doesn't create additional database columns for custom fields. That's one of the great concepts that make Wordpress so smart and flexible.

Comment: what I really want to do is to ask for extra information when a new member is registered. Like birthday, gender, and other things. With the help of add-ons I can do it in the frontend as much as I can. That is, it only records "e-mail, nickname, password" in the "wp-users" section of the database. I want to save extra questions like gender and age in the database. Because I will have to pull this information out of the database in the future.